# wgs84 and maxscaledenom on mapserver &mode=tile&tilemode=gmap&tile={x}+{y}+{z}.png

Tags: mapserver

http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html

`MAXSCALEDENOM 24000`

For me this only seem to work when using `UNITS dd` and `wgs84` and using qgis, as soon as i use leaflet and `&mode=tile&tilemode=gmap&tile={x}+{y}+{z}.png` i need to use`UNITS meters` and mercator. `&mode=tile&tilemode=gmap&tile={x}+{y}+{z}.png` doesn't work using `MAXSCALEDENOM` in combination with `UNITS dd` and `wgs84` everything else works.

Debug message tells me scale is to small when using wgs84

Is this a bug or related to something else? Below example works until you switch everything to wgs84 then you need to comment out `MAXSCALEDENOM 24000` or you get a empty png in leaflet at any zoom level.

```
MAP
  NAME "TEST"
  SHAPEPATH "/wms"
  CONFIG  "MS_ERRORFILE" "stderr"
  UNITS METERS
  # UNITS dd
  # EXTENT 6.024789 47.513195 15.008623 54.838047
  STATUS ON
  DEBUG 0

  PROJECTION
    # "init=epsg:4326"
    "init=epsg:3857"
  END

  WEB
    METADATA
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
      "wms_title" "TEST"
      # "wms_onlineresource" "..."
      # "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:3857"
      "wms_format" "image/png"
      "tile_map_edge_buffer" "10"
      "tile_metatile_level" "0"
    END
  END

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "AGGPNG"
    DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
    EXTENSION "png"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    IMAGEMODE RGBA
  END

  LAYER
    NAME test
    DATA test
    TYPE line
    MAXSCALEDENOM 24000

    CLASS
      STYLE
        width 8
        color "#000000"
        offset 0 -99
      END
    END

  END

END
```

Comment: MAXSCALEDENOM does work with web mercator proj and units = meter. See this project for instance: https://github.com/mapserver/basemaps

Comment: Please provide the map-file to see what's wrong

Comment: Yes sorry i got confused, apparently it's more complicated, let me edit my question

Comment: added map file example

Comment: See the accepted answer of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78557/mapserver-and-openlayers-properly-using-maxscaledenom-in-mapfile-google-basela

Comment: Thx thats exactly it